# NSDate delay date change

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

This is probably a simple solution but does anyone know how to delay the NSDate change past midnight? Any insight would be really helpful, thanks!

**Edit:**
I am currently getting the date this way and displaying a locations data based on that day. But, much like the NSDate is logically supposed to work, it switches to the next day at midnight. I want the date to change at 3am instead of at 12am.

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
today = [f stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Should I just use the time instead of using NSDate? I am a bit of a noob to iOS so any insight would be helpful. Thanks for your responses already.

Comment: Change your time zone...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I don't want Saturday to switch to Sunday until 3am, or any specific time. So basically I want to offset the date change by a few hours.

Comment: That's not how dates work, in the real world or iOS. You'll need to put some logic in to check the time.

Comment: I don' t understand the problem. Please show some code with actual and expected results.

Comment: What I mean - if you want to say "saturday" when it is really "sunday" (since you don't get to make the rules, as @kevin pointed out), you could set the time zone of your device "three zones to the West". In NY, this would mean "What day is it in LA". But you would then have to patch things together for whatever you are trying to display (in other words, you can't make **the OS** say "it is 2 o'clock in the morning and still Saturday", but **you** can create a display "It is 2 o'clock in the morning. I call this Saturday (I took a peak at what day it is in LA)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that I do not yet understand *why* you want to display a "wrong" weekday
name, but the following code should do what you want. This is only one of various ways
to achieve your task.

Convert date to "date components:"

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Subtract one day if necessary:

```
if (comp.hour < 3) {
    comp.day -= 1;
}
```

Convert adjusted components back to date:

```
NSDate *adjustedDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
```

Your original code, now using the adjusted date:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *today = [f stringFromDate:adjustedDate];
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. For some context: It is an application that displays bars' specials, hours, and so forth and I wanted our users to open the app for the specials for that day, which obviously goes past midnight.